# getting my firefox bash script to print a line every time a links is visited

Tags: bash, url, hyperlink, show

hi there I have a part of code in my bash script that i need help with 
i am using the following code to open links from a text file

```
while read line; do 
    firefox -new-tab "$line" & 2>/dev/null
    sleep 15
done < file1
```

this does work perfectly fine but i would like to have the script print a set message i.e
(Link vistied) everytime it opens a new URL.

Also is there any way I can get my bash script to always stay on top of all windows ?

Comment: Do you mean print a message every time an instance of firefox opens a new URL?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the message is as easy as this:

```
while read line; do 
    firefox -new-tab "$line" & 2>/dev/null
    echo "Visted $line"
    sleep 15
done < file1
```

You don't say what OS you're using, but, given bash, I'm assuming Linux, so you can usually keep the terminal window on the top by right clicking on the title bar and choosing the appropriate item from the menu. That does vary from desktop environment to desktop environment though.